# Step to prove twin primes' conjecture: $\liminf_{n\to\infty}(p_{n+1}-p_n)<7\cdot10^7$

Tags: number-theory, twin-primes

Today I have found that the Chinese mathematician Yitang Zhang has proven in 2013 that the sequence $d_n=p_{n+1}-p_n$ where $p_n$ is the $n$th prime has a finite inferior limit (and in fact, lesser than 70 millions).

I'm only a High School teacher, so I have not access to the article. I'm pretty sure that I can't understand it, but in any case I want to try.

Has anybody here read it? How dificult to read is this article?

Comment: Not sure how hard it is to read. It undoubtedly uses some quite sophisticated machinery. You can probably find more information by going through the various links on http://michaelnielsen.org/polymath1/index.php?title=Bounded_gaps_between_primes where they improved the bounds a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go on Terence Tao's homepage, where you will find two recent preprints/articles by himself and other people which improve upon Zhang's result (the new lower bound is much smaller), as well as an account on the "state of the art".